# Sequence of functions, pointwise but not almost uniform convergence to $0$.

Tags: measure-theory, uniform-convergence

I have the function sequence:
$$f_{n}(x)=\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)=\begin{cases}1, & \text{ if } x>n\\0, & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Why does this sequence converges almost everywhere on $\mathbb R$ to $0$? So the measure of the set when $f_{n}$ does not converge to $0$ shouldn't be infinite? And I don't understand why this sequence does not converge almost uniformly to $0$.

Please help me with this!

Comment: That's for a particular $n$. But $f_n(x)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for every $x$ - specifically, when $n>x,$ $f_n(x)=0$.

Comment: I agree that $f_{n}(x)=0$, when $n\ge x$, but I still dont understand why the sequence converges to 0..I am a begginer in the mathematical analysis.Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: What does converge to zero mean, in your definition? Can't a value be $>0$ for some $n$ and still converge to zero?

Comment: The whole point of a sequence like this is to show that our definitions don't always match some of our intuitions. So you have to go back to what your definition says - if you try to apply your intuition only, you will be tripped up. So state the definition, and then show that this sequence matches that definition.

Comment: I know that: a sequence $f_{n}$ converges almost everywhere to f if the set $\{x|f_{n}(x) does not converge to f(x)\}$ has measure 0.

Comment: Since $f_n(x)\to 0$ for every $x$, then the set of values where it does not converge is empty, hence measure $0$. Pick any $x$, and I can show that the sequence $f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots$ converges to zero.

Comment: Ok, with your last eplanation, I think I get it...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_n=\sup_x{|f_n(x)-0|}$ as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition). The sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly iff $a_n \to 0$. But for each $n$ there exists $x_n>n$ and therefore $f_n(x_n)=1$ which implies $a_n=1$ for each $n\mathbb \in N$. Hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=1$$ and therefore the sequence does not converge almost uniformly to $0$. Contrary the sequence converges pointwise to $0$. For each $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $n_x \in \mathbb N$ such that $x<n_x$. Then it is the fact that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_{n_x+n}(x)=0$$

Comment: What is $f_{n,+n}$?

Comment: I shift the index. $\lim f_n(x)=\lim_{f_{15+n}(x)}$ for example. Do you find this wrong? Moreover it is pointwise limit. So for each $x$ we take a different shift. Is that ok?

Comment: Oh the subindex in $n_x$ looked like a coman to my poor eyes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, ok. Perhaps $n(x)$ instead of $n_x$ would be a better notation. So, this is ok?

Comment: Fir Jimmy: to show that the sequence doesnt converge almost uniformly to 0, you used the theorem for a sequence of bounded functions?

Comment: @user308560 No, the theorem I used holds in general, according to my reference. But since $f_n(x)\le 1$ for each $n$, the functions $f_n$ are indeed bounded by $1$.

Comment: Can you tell me ,please, what theorem did you use exactly? I know that this is used inly for bounded  function.

Comment: @user308560 These functions are bounded. And I actually used the definition. For any $N \in \mathbb N$ there is some $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f_n(x)=1>ε$ no matter the choice of $ε$. This shows no uniform convergence.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! forgive me for troubling you so..

Comment: @user308560 No problem. It is good practice for both of us.